# Disable actionbar Up button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to disable the Up button in the Support Actionbar on certain user actions. According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setHomeButtonEnabled(boolean), setHomeButtonEnabled should do what I want. However, the button remains clickable. (I can disable the other icons in the actionbar without problem).

I am trying to disable it from a fragment.
My code to disable is:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {

    if (isUpdating) {


        getBaseActivity().getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_backgrey));
        getBaseActivity().getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

        for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
            menu.getItem(i).setEnabled(false);
            menu.getItem(i).getIcon().setAlpha(64);
        }
    } else {

        getBaseActivity().getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getBaseActivity().getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_back));
        for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
            menu.getItem(i).setEnabled(true);
            menu.getItem(i).getIcon().setAlpha(255);
        }
    }
}
```

and my code in activity onCreate is:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_back));
```

and my Fragment onCreate contains
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

Comment: "I want the icon to remain, but greyed out" -- no, you appear to want it disabled ("the button remains clickable"), and AFAIK there is no API for that. You're welcome to try to use Hierarchy View or **`uiautomatorviewer`** to try to find a unique widget ID for that `ImageView`/`ImageButton`, then get it via `findViewById()` and call `setEnabled(false)` on it. However, this will be fragile, as there is no requirement that the widget keep the same ID over time, etc.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. I don't want the button to be clickable when I disable it. However, with the current code, it does remain clickable

Comment: That lines up completely with what I wrote in my original comment.

Comment: ok, I misread your comment. In that case, what exactly does **setHomeButtonEnabled** do? Since the docs describe it like it should do what I want?

Comment: It does not grey out the icon, for one thing. `setHomeButtonEnabled()` controls whether or not you get notified via `onOptionsItemSelected()` about clicks, IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment add

```
getBaseActivity().getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

and in your Activity add

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Comment: This hides the icon. I want the icon to remain, but greyed out

Comment: I don't think android supports that. You should stuck to the design patterns that android introduces since this the way user expect your app to behave. https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html If that's not possible at all you might have a look at custom action provider. Maybe you can use them to fake that button.

Comment: One hack that you could do is don't specify the parent activity in the manifest fie. In that case the back arrow will show but will not respond to onClick

Answer (score 0):

In oncreate() setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled should be set to false as well.

```
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)

Comment: I do not want to disable onCreate, but after user clicks a button. I call invalidateOptionsMenu(), then I try to disable in onPrepareOptionsMenu as above
As you can see, I already call setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false)